# Uniqueidentifier as Identity in SQL Server CE?

Tags: sql-server-ce, identity-column

In SQL Server CE can I create an identity column with  data type `uniqueidentifier`? If so, how? If not, why not?

I have tried creating it with "New Table"from the Server Explorer in VS2010, and the Identity option only gets enabled when the  type is int.

Edit:

According to EricEJ's suggestion I did make the column PK. I also set it to be a "RowGuid"

```
   CREATE TABLE [MyTable] (
      [Id] uniqueidentifier ROWGUIDCOL 
      ...
```

I don't know exactly the intended purpose of the `RowGuid` property, but it seem to have the desired effect, namely to automatically create new default guid-values upon insert, without having to create them in code. It would be nice to have the default values to be sequential guids, but this doesn't seem to be supported by SQL Server CE.

Comment: Good thinking - ROWGUIDCOL is like setting a default value of NEWID() for SQL CE - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210989.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only supported type for IDENTITY is int or bigint. But you can have a Guid/uniqueidentifier as primary key, and set a value of this in code using Guid.NewGuid().