# Insert statement when having GUID as primary key

Tags: c#, sql, insert, sql-server-ce, guid

Is there a way to insert a row in SQL CE using the INSERT Statement when I have a GUID field.

In C#, I use

```
ID = Guid.NewGuid()
```

But in SQL console I can't find a **keyword** to do this.

I've found just this one :

```
> Insert into Customer (ID, Name) values ('f5c7181e-e117-4a98-bc06-733638a3a264','MyCustomer')
```

What about if I have a lot of rows to insert ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [uniqueidentifier as Identity in SQLCE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763609/uniqueidentifier-as-identity-in-sqlce)

Comment: You can use the guid generated from code, but you'll need to convert it to a VARCHAR(255).  For example: `Insert into Customer (ID, Name) values (Convert(VARCHAR(255),'f5c7181e-e117-4a98-bc06-733638a3a264'),'MyCustomer')`.  If you don't care about using the GUID generated in your C# code, then `Newid()` is perfect.  See [Microsoft Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190348.aspx).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try to use `Newid()` in Sql server to generate GUID

Answer (score 1):

Can't you use NEWID() function?

Comment: How, because I'm using SQL Compact Edition (very limited functionality)

Answer (score 1):

To have a `GUID` on a field you can set the default of a column to be `NEWSEQUENTIALID()`. So, for example:

```
CREATE TABLE tableName (
    Guid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT NEWSEQUENTIALID(),
    Name VARCHAR(100)
);
```

Then insert into the table by executing the following query:

```
INSERT INTO tableName (Name) VALUES ('Test');
```

I'm not sure if `NEWSEQUENTIALID()` is supported in CE or not, as I've never used CE for development.

Answer (score 0):

In C#, GUID are lower case so use `LOWER(NEWID())` in SQL if you want them to look similar.